# Displaying form_for for comment method in show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, form-for

I am trying to display a comment form in the view of my types model (types#show)

The routes are defined as follows

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root to: "products#index"
  resources :types do
    member do
        get :vote, :as => :vote
      post "vote" => "types#vote"
      get :comment, :as => :comment
      post "comment" => "types#comment"
    end
  end
  resources :models
  resources :products
  resources :brands
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

The comment method in types_controller.rb

```
  def comment
    user = current_or_guest_user
    @type = Type.find(params[:id])
    user_review = params[:review]
    @type.review(user_review, user)
    redirect_to @type, notice: 'Thank you for your comment.'
  end
```

I am having troubles setting the form_for correctly in the views

```
<%= form_for comment_type_path(@type) do |f| %>

    <div><h3>How likely are you to recommend our service to your friends, family or colleagues?</h3></div>



    <div><h3>Can you please tell us why you gave us this score?</h3></div>
    <div class="field-box">
      <br>
      <%= f.text_area :review, class: "form-control", rows: "4" %><br>
    </div>




    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit 'Vote', class: 'btn-flat success new-product' %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
```

gives me the following error:
No route matches [POST] "/types/5"

```
<%= form_for @type, url: comment_type_path(@type), method: :post do |f| %>
    <div><h3>How likely are you to recommend our service to your friends, family or colleagues?</h3></div>



    <div><h3>Can you please tell us why you gave us this score?</h3></div>
    <div class="field-box">
      <br>
      <%= f.text_area :review, class: "form-control", rows: "4" %><br>
    </div>




    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit 'Vote', class: 'btn-flat success new-product' %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
```

gives

ArgumentError in Types#show
Showing /home/jan/Documents/supplement/app/views/types/show.html.erb where line #62 raised:

wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)

Comment: What is on line 62 of `show.html.erb`? ArgumentError can be because of your some method call. Your last `form_for` syntax is correct

Comment: <%= f.text_area :review, class: "form-control", rows: "4" %><br>

Comment: can you create [`gist`](https://gist.github.com) with your whole view and full backtrace?

Comment: I hope thats what you wanted: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/slucha/d014b8b21e98f0f8d755ff145aaba2eb) thanks!

Comment: I don't see `@type` in `comment_type_path` [here](https://gist.github.com/slucha/d014b8b21e98f0f8d755ff145aaba2eb#file-show-html-erb-L54)

Comment: Yes sorry, U have not changed it back after asita kalenas suggestion from below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155589/discussion-between-kiddorails-and-jan).

Comment: show.html.erb and backtrace updated now

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your `form_for` with below code

`<%= form_for @type, url: comment_type_path, method: "post" do |f| %>`

Comment: This gives the same error as above:

ArgumentError in Types#show
Showing /home/jan/Documents/supplement/app/views/types/show.html.erb where line #62 raised:

wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)

in this line
 `<%= f.text_area :review, class: "form-control", rows: "4" %><br>`

Comment: Try this `<%= f.text_area(:review, class: "form-control", rows: "4") %>`

Comment: Thank you, still the same error. I am confused to why this shows me the argument error for types#show and which arguments are missing. This does not show from the error message

Comment: @asmitakalena there is no difference between these two text_area calls

Comment: Note: **The above is indeed same. Please ignore. My bad** Okay, please provide the `as` option with your route for post request. Something like `post "comment" => "types#comment", as: "comment"` and use the generated helper path in the form_for url

Comment: Tried this already and still get the wrong # of arguments error, sorry